# Set local documentation for android studio 0.8

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to set local documentation path in android studio 0.8, but i cant do this. I google this, but i can't find any solution for this problem. Can any body help me please.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in Android Studio 2.1 :
First, you have to see which Android SDK you are using from the `Project Structure`. Currently I am using Android 7.0 because the problem was caused by Android 7.1.1 SDK (I will explain why).

[image: Project Structure]

Now, open the `Standalone SDK Manager`. Find the SDK version that you use, then select `Documentation for Android SDK` then `Install package` and you will have a local copy of the docs automatically used by your AS.

[image: Android Standalone SDK Manager]

As you can see, there is no documentation available to download for Android 7.1.1, that's why Android Studio was loading it from the Android developer website.

So, the solution is to use an Android SDK that has a downloadable documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.Documentation was empty when I used documentation shortcut(ctrl + Q) and I also couldn't change the documentation paths because it wasn't there! so here is the solution:

1. Delete  **C:\Users[user name].AndroidStudioBeta** folder.(Don't worry it just delete your configurations! ;) )
2. rename **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk**  (SDK path)folder to something else.
3. run Android studio and make sure you don't import you configurations.
4. Now you can change new sdk folder's name back to SDK .
5. Android studio will ask you new path for SDK ,so you can continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the documentation using SDK manager, it'll get added automatically when you add an SDK in "Project Structure"

In Android Studio, You can verify this by selecting File -> Project Structure -> SDKs (on left pane).

Select one added SDK from the list, Select the tab "Documentation Paths" from right most pane. Check whether the path is automatically added. If not, add it manually by clicking the plus (+) button on right.

Comment: Hi gnuanu. In android studio 0.8 there is only sdk location on left pan, so I can't choose any SDK to set documentation path.

Comment: I didn't clearly get what you mean. Can you please post a screenshot of the "Project Structure" dialog

Comment: @ebi, Looks strange. AS 0.8 ships with a preconfigured Android SDK (I had API 20 preconfigured). BTW, This is what my ["Project Structure"](http://i.imgur.com/glEbHAV.png) Window looks like.

Comment: Latest versions of AS (1.0+) don't have that settings, at least I haven't found.

Comment: @Arthur, it depends on the build system you use, Ant or Gradle. Projects built with AS will get configured in Gradle by default. But you can open and build Ant projects which are preconfigured using IntelliJ IDEA. In Ant projects you'll see a Project Structure dialog like the one I gave in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could accomplish this on AS 1.0 is to run local web server (Abyss Web Server) to host the documentation from here (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\docs). And use Fiddler as proxy to remap url developer.android.com to 127.0.0.1:8080 (Abyss address), setting Fiddler's address as proxy in AS settings.

Oh, and created a .bat file to run and stop this all together.

Really dirty trick, but the only I found.

Comment: I have the opposite problem. I am using AS 2.1 and it shows the local documentation in a web browser when I clicked a link on the Quick Documentation. Can I make it show the web version (developer.android.com) instead? I want to use the web version because I want to use Stylish for a dark theme.